# My Nav Host cant Trigger fragments on action

Tags: java, android, xml

I have implemented the new architecture navigation but unfortunately my nav host cant trigger the fragments it stays on Home fragment as the starting destination but it does not do anything it stays on the home fragment only while the other fragments cant be triggered

**Here is my navhost xml file**

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_cict"
    app:startDestination="@id/homefragment">


    <!--first fragmenet-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homefragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"
        android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.HomeFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home2_to_explore"
            app:destination="@+id/clearfragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <!--second fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/clearfragment"
        android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.ClearFragmentCenterofInformation"
        android:label="fragment_clear"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_clearcict">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/clear_to_status"
            app:destination="@+id/statusfragment"/>

    </fragment>

    <!--third fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/statusfragment"
        android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.StatusFragment"
        android:label="fragment_status"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_status">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/status_to_print"
            app:destination="@+id/printfragment"/>

    </fragment>

    <!--fourth fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/printfragment"
        android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.PrintFormFragment"
        android:label="fragment_print"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_printform">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/status_to_print"
            app:destination="@+id/accountfragment"/>

    </fragment>

    <!--fifth fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/accountfragment"
        android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.AccountFragment"
        android:label="fragment_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account">
    </fragment>


</navigation>```
````

**Here is where i implemented the nav host on the main activity**

``

````
package com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.R;


public class MainActivityCenterofInformation extends AppCompatActivity {


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_maincict);
        setUpNavigation ();


    }

    public  void setUpNavigation(){
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById (R.id.bottom_navigationcict);
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager ()
                .findFragmentById (R.id.fragment_nav_host_cict);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController (bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController ());
    }



}```
````

Comment: I think we need to see some code where you implement your nav activity.

Comment: have updated the question bro check it @KristyWelsh

Comment: I don't think bottom navigation goes this way.  You are not really implementing Android navigational components with what you are doing.  Your nav should go something like:  findNavController().navigate(
            YourNavigationFragmentDirections.actionBottomNavDetailActivity(
                workPackageId
            )
        )